# How to view number of views on mobile app

Tags: support

How does one view the number of views to a particular post?  I can’t seem to find it.  Perhaps someone can send a screenshot to help?

Comment: For the record, for issues not specific to physics.SE, you usually get faster and/or more comprehensive responses at [meta.SE]

Comment: Another bugbear on tablets, on mine at least, I can't delete a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear: the mobile app (applying to both the iOS and the android apps) is **not** a full-featured version of this site. The full-featured version is the desktop site as seen on [officially supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need); if you do something else (including using the mobile website or either of the mobile apps) and some bit of the site functionality doesn't work, then that's because you're not using the full-featured version. If you want that feature, either switch to the desktop version on a supported browser, or ask a feature request for that feature to be ported.

Feature requests like that are in principle on-topic here, but the attention from both community and the dev team that they'll gather is rather minimal; they are very much best posed on [the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com), and indeed (like your specific example, over at [How to see the number of views of a post on mobile app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232077/how-to-see-the-number-of-views-of-a-post-on-mobile-app)) they often have been asked already. However, it's important to note that for frills like this on the app, given that [some usage-critical features remain unimplemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281120/184688), the chance of a speedy implementation is extremely slim.