# Question ID on mobile app

Tags: support, flagging, mobile-app

I was wondering how do I find the question ID of a particular question in order to flag it as a duplicate.  How can I find the question ID of any particular question?

Comment: [As you've been told before](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10347), "To be clear: the mobile app [...] is not a full-featured version of this site. The full-featured version is the desktop site as seen on officially supported browsers; if you do something else (including using the mobile website or either of the mobile apps) and some bit of the site functionality doesn't work, then that's because you're not using the full-featured version. If you want that feature, either switch to the desktop version on a supported browser, or ask a feature request for that feature to be ported."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the question ID. Click on "share" and copy the link to the question to your clipboard, then insert that into the close dialogue.

Comment: Yes that would help.  But how about the ID?  I just want to know

Comment: @XcoderX do you not see that the link that "share" generates is the standard link that includes the ID?